# Docker namespaces and SELinux not working

Tags: debian, selinux, namespaces

My system:

- Debian 9 Stretch
- Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
- SELinux

This is just running fine.

But, if I also activate Namespace Remapping (default, using the dockremap User), I can't run or start any of my Containers.

```
 # docker run hello-world
nsenter: failed to unshare namespaces: Operation not permitted
container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:247: running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 34\""
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:247: running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 34\"".
```

If I disable SELinux enforcing, (or namespaces), everything is just fine again.

Using audit2allow did not work.

Does someone have some tips & tricks for me to get the whole thing working?

Comment: What's the output from audit2allow when you set SELinux to permissive before firing up the container?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to troubleshoot on Debian, but this definitely works on Fedora/RHEL/CentOS. The SELinux policies are designed for containers and mapping works. I just did it today with podman rootless containers.